# Как определить DIV с наибольшей высотой?

Tags: jquery

Есть HTML-код

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

В блоках с классом `inner` разное количество текста.
Как определить блок с классом `inner`, имеющий наибольшую высоту?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var maxHeight = 0;
var highestElement = {};
$('.block>div').each(function() {
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    if (thisHeight>maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = thisHeight;
        highestElement = $(this);
    }
});
```

Прокручиваем через `div`ы, сверяем высоты.
Храним самый высокий в `highestElement`